# JSPs that render articles in Liferay 6

Tags: java, jsp, liferay-6

I want to overwrite in a hook the JSPs that render articles in Liferay 6 to display a custom field on every article. In String_PAGE constant from 
liferay-portal-src-6.0.6\util-taglib\src\com\liferay\taglib\ui\JournalArticleTag.java.
there is a JSP, which I think is the one I need to overwrite. The JSP is found here:
liferay-portal-src-6.0.6\portal-web\docroot\html\taglib\ui\journal_article\page.jsp.

I overwrite this JSP, but there are no visible changes when loading articles.

I'm wondering if this is the right JSP or maybe there is something I'm not doing right.

Comment: There is no single jsp that render article at all places in Liferay. There are multiple jsps , separate for each portlet like Web Content in Control Panel its  `html\portlet\journal\view_article.jsp` ,`For Web Content Display its: html\portlet\journal_content\view.jsp`

Comment: Hi, Pankaj, thank you for your answer! Can you detail a bit on how can I find all the JSPs I need, I'm not very familiar with Liferay. In liferay-portal-src-6.0.6\portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\journal\ I found view.jsp but no view_article.jsp. In liferay-portal-src-6.0.6\portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\journal_content I found view.jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Web Content Display portlet you need to override this jsp:

`...\html\portlet\journal_content\view.jsp`

github: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/journal_content/view.jsp

here is docu how to override the jsp:

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/overriding-a-j-4

Comment: Hi, Mark, indeed you were right on Web Content Display. Do you know what is the JSP I need to override for Asset Publisher ? Thanks!

Comment: I found out the answer on Asset Publisher. I came across https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6643194 and I managed to add something on the interface by overriding liferay-portal-src-6.0.6\portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\asset_publisher\display\abstracts.jsp and liferay-portal-src-6.0.6\portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\asset_publisher\view_content.jsp